# Ajaxbutton in Yii to replace a normal link

Tags: ajax, yii

I'm using the blog demo given with Yii and I try to understand how to render comments just under the select post without reloading the page.

The principle of the demo is :

post/index action
- render index.php which call _view.php  through ClistView. 
  (so it gives a list of posts and for each post a link to the associated comments.)

- the link to the associated comments,  calls the post/view action

the link contains the following code

```
<?php echo CHtml::link("Comments ({$data->commentCount})",$data->url); ?>
```

(which gives the link  -->

```
localhost/blog/index.php/post/2/postTitle
```

2 = the post_id

I want to replace it by

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxButton ("Comments ({$data->commentCount})",
                              CController::createUrl($data->url)
                              );
```

but it produces the following link

```
localhost/blog/index.php/blog/index.php/post/2/postTitle?_=1395482622334
```

and I got the 404 error

the post/view action

- renderPartial post/_view for the specific post
- renderPartial post/_comments which list the associated comments with a for loop.
- renderPartial comment/_form

Can you give me an idea of what's wrong?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CController creates URL from base directory which is protected.It Creates a relative URL for the specified action defined in this controller.
createUrl function produces URL like

```
localhost/blog/index.php/
```

But your $data->url also contains `blog/index.php/` thats why you are getting it doubled. You can simply write

```
CController::createUrl('controller/action',array('key'=>'value'))
```

Do not put `blog/index.php/` in your $data->Url.If you need to then you can simply write it as

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxButton ("Comments ({$data->commentCount})",
                              $data->url
                              );
```

Comment: . Thank you, now it doesnt show the 404 error.  Now, I have to change my action to check ajax call.

Comment: you are welcome. Glad it worked for you. Just a side note for ajax calls that its results are not shown in browser but you can view it in firebug.